# How can I change this code to swift 2 using core data?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to follow this example along, but I realized it isn't in swift 2. I am new to swift so I wouldn't know how to change it to something different. can someone help?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var costLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentLabel: UITextField!

    let maContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func saveClient(sender: AnyObject) {
        let personDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: maContext)
    }

    // let person = Person(entity: personDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: maContext)

    person.fName = firstName.text
    person.lName = lastName.text
    person.time = timeLabel.int
    person.cost = costLabel.int
    person.comments = commentLabel.text

    var error:NSError?

    maContext?.save(&error)

    if let err = error
    {
        let a  = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: err.localizedFailureReason, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        a.show()
    }
    else{
        let a = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Your Record is saved" , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

        a.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use Xcode's Convert to Latest Swift Syntax tool?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't do much

Comment: If you don't tell us what exactly this is supposed to do, the definition of "not working" is too broad for us to help you out effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll try to answer your question as best as I can.

The code appears to be Swift 2 compliant. I don't think the CoreData API's have been upgraded to leverage the new `do / try / catch` syntax for error handling so the `&error` in the save for the `NSManagedObjectContext` seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your code is correct should be something like this:

do {

```
    try maContext.save()
    let a = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Your Record is saved" , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    a.show()
} catch let error as NSError {
    let a  = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: err.localizedFailureReason, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    a.show()
}
```

instead of your code:

```
var error:NSError?

    maContext?.save(&error)

    if let err = error
    {
        let a  = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: err.localizedFailureReason, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        a.show()
    }
    else{
        let a = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Your Record is saved" , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

        a.show()
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe that NSManagedObjectContext supports the new Swift error handling syntax.